# java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to get camera info

Tags: android

In my PhotoCaptureActivity.java's onCreate() I have:

```
OrientationEventListener oeL = new  OrientationEventListener(this) {        
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                 if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
                 try {
                     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();                
                     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(currentCameraId, info);
                     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
                     int rotation = 0;
                     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
                     } else {  // back-facing camera
                         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
                     }
                     if(camera != null) {
                         Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                         parameters.setRotation(rotation);
                         savingRotation = rotation;
                     }
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                     return;
                 }
            }
         };
         oeL.enable();
```

Exception occurred on this line: `android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(currentCameraId, info);`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to get camera info
       at android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.java)
       at cic.signin.macio.jun.activities.PhotoCaptureActivity$3.onOrientationChanged(PhotoCaptureActivity.java:70)
       at android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl.onSensorChanged(OrientationEventListener.java:143)
       at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SensorManager.java:584)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

My question is: if android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInf(currentCameraId, info) in OrientationEventListener's onOrientationChanged() was called too frequently caused the exception? How to solve the issue? btw, this exception didn't occur on 4.0 and 4.1, only occurred on certain device.

Comment: Is this occurring only on a Galaxy Nexus? Most links I found related to this stacktrace referred to that device.

Comment: Crashlytics shows UNKNOWN M713, I don't actually know this type of device

Comment: I'm guessing it's a hardware issue. If I were you, I'd try to get more info on the devices that have these errors.

Comment: First you need to release the first instance of camera before getting the new info object.

Comment: I think @RohitHeera is right, you need the camera instance first to get the camera info. :) Goodluck pal!

Comment: If this is happening on a Nexus 5, there is a bug filed for this with AOSP. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160609

Comment: Did you add the camera permissions in your manifest?

Comment: class Camera.CameraInfo is deprecated in api 21

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess here -
its not related to your code, reset the device and try again.
Sometimes my Camera (or even the flash stops working) and the only to fix it is to reset the device.